# Use realloc() in function

Tags: arrays, c, function, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void Increase(int *array1,int *Nums) {
    int*array2 = realloc(array1,(*Nums+1)*sizeof(int));
    array2[*Nums] = 13;
    array2[*Nums-1] = 14;
    ++(*Nums);
}


int main() {
    int NumOfElements=0,i;
    int*array=(int*)malloc(0*sizeof(int));
    Increase(array,&NumOfElements);
    for(i=0;i<NumOfElements;i++) {
        printf("%d  ", array[i]);
    }
    free(array);
}
```

How many elements will be in the array in `main()` if I run this program?

Does the `Increase()` function increase the number of memory cells of the array in `main()`, or will the array in `main()` still just have 0 memory cells?

Comment: It's amazing how many errors one can cram into such a short program. This program will not work at all.

Comment: This won't work; among other things, `array2` is a local variable.

Comment: You should be asking yourself "why does `realloc` return a value? what's the purpose of it? could it just have returned `void`?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [realloc manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc):

> The realloc() function returns a pointer to the newly allocated
> memory, which is suitably aligned for any kind of variable **and may be
> different from ptr**, or NULL if the request fails.

... so the answer to your question will depend on whether the call to `realloc()` was able to change the memory-allocation's size in-place, or not.

If `realloc()` was able to do an in-place resize (e.g. because the heap had allocated a larger-than-necessary array for the original `malloc()` call, allowing `realloc()` to simply mark some of the extra bytes in the buffer as in-use), then `realloc()` would return the same pointer that was passed in to it as an argument, which is the same memory-location that `main()` points to via `array`.  In this scenario, `main()` could access the now-larger-array via `array` without any problems.

On the other hand, if `realloc()` wasn't able to do an in-place resize, then `realloc()` would be forced to allocate a newer/larger array, copy over the contents of the old array, `free()` the old array, and return the pointer to the larger array.  In that case, `array2` would point to a different location in memory than `array` and `array1`, and (worse), after `Increase()` returns, `main()` would invoke undefined behavior by dereferencing `array`, which is (at that point) a dangling pointer because `realloc()` freed the memory it used to point to.

Answer (score 0):

I think one is intending to implement a common container known a [dynamic array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) for use in a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) (or similar structure.)

```
#include <stddef.h>

struct int_stack { int *data; size_t size, capacity; };

struct int_stack int_stack(void);
void int_stack_(struct int_stack *);
int *int_stack_new(struct int_stack *);
```

This is what I'd use as `int_stack.h`. Notice that it's logical size and it's capacity are not necessarily the same, but `size <= capacity`.

```
#include "int_stack.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

/** Initialises `s` to idle. */
struct int_stack int_stack(void) {
    struct int_stack s;
    s.data = 0;
    s.capacity = s.size = 0;
    return s;
}

/** Destroys `s`; returns it idle. */
void int_stack_(struct int_stack *const s) {
    free(s->data);
    *s = int_stack();
}

/** Ensures `min_capacity` of `s`. Returns success, otherwise, `errno` will be
 set. */
static int int_stack_reserve(struct int_stack *const s, const size_t min) {
    size_t c0;
    int *data;
    const size_t max_size = (size_t)-1 / sizeof *s->data, min_size = 3;
    if(s->data) {
        if(min <= s->capacity) return 1;
        c0 = s->capacity < min_size ? min_size : s->capacity;
    } else { /* Idle. */
        if(!min) return 1;
        c0 = min_size;
    }
    if(min > max_size) return errno = ERANGE, 0;
    /* `c_n = a1.625^n`, approximation golden ratio `\phi ~ 1.618`. */
    while(c0 < min) {
        size_t c1 = c0 + (c0 >> 1) + (c0 >> 3);
        if(c0 > c1) { c0 = max_size; break; }
        c0 = c1;
    }
    if(!(data = realloc(s->data, sizeof *s->data * c0)))
        { if(!errno) errno = ERANGE; return 0; }
    s->data = data, s->capacity = c0;
    return 1;
}

/** Increases the capacity of `s` to at least `n` elements beyond the size.
 Returns the start of the buffered space at the back of the array or null and
 `errno`. */
static int *int_stack_buffer(struct int_stack *const s, const size_t n) {
    if(s->size > (size_t)-1 - n) { errno = ERANGE; return 0; } /* Unlikely. */
    return int_stack_reserve(s, s->size + n) && s->data ? s->data + s->size : 0;
}

/** Adds `n` elements to the back of `s` and returns a pointer to the elements.
 Null indicates an error and `errno` will be set. */
static int *int_stack_append(struct int_stack *const s, const size_t n) {
    int *buffer;
    if(!(buffer = int_stack_buffer(s, n))) return 0;
    return s->size += n, buffer;
}

/** Adds one new element of `s` and returns it as an uninitialized pointer or
 null and `errno`. */
int *int_stack_new(struct int_stack *const s) { return int_stack_append(s, 1); }
```

This is an example of what I'd use as the implementation `int_stack.c`. The function `int_stack_reserve` is where the `realloc` is called once the size reaches the capacity. A temporary `data` is assigned the `realloc`; this is checked for error, then assigned into `s->data`. Reserving a geometrically increasing capacity will avoid the cost of expanding each time. Thus, the array will have amortized cost of `O(n)` to insert `n` elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "int_stack.h"

int main(void) {
    int status = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    int *e1, *e2;
    struct int_stack stack = int_stack();
    if(!(e1 = int_stack_new(&stack)) || !(e2 = int_stack_new(&stack))) {
        status = EXIT_FAILURE;
        perror("stack");
    } else {
        *e1 = 13;
        *e2 = 14;
        for(size_t i=0; i<stack.size; i++) {
            printf("%d  ", stack.data[i]);
        }
        fputc('\n', stdout);
    }
    int_stack_(&stack);
    return status;
}
```

Instead of a fixed-size, we now have unlimited size, but one has to check for out-of-memory condition.